# React mui TextField label is cut off in Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, label, textfield

I am currently facing difficulties with React MUI's `Autocomplete` component. The `Autocomplete` is placed in a `FormControl` component.

In the `renderInput` prop of the Autocomplete, I added a TextField, but its label is being cut:

[image]

I tried playing with padding & margins, but it does not change anything and I do not know where the problem resides.

My code looks like this:

```js
<Autocomplete
    autoHighlight
    value={value ?? null}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        updateValue(newValue);
    }}
    inputValue={inputValue}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
    }}
    sx={{ overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", p: 0, m: 0 }}
    options={displayedOptions}
    getOptionValue={(option) => option?.optionValue ?? ""}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.optionLabel ?? ""}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          required={required}
          label={label}
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the styles.

From this `sx` prop:

```
 sx={{ overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", p: 0, m: 0 }}
```

You need to delete this part `overflow: "hidden",` so it should be like:

```
sx={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", p: 0, m: 0 }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was the issue indeed !